# Determining Slug Before and After Edit

Tags: posts, pages, slug

If I were to edit a post or a page, how would I determine what the slug was before the edit, and again afterwards to compare them and see if it was changed? Also, would the same method work for any Custom Post Types created, or is that done differently?

Answer (score 1):

If the post/page was previously published, and you changed the slug when you edited the page, the old slug gets put into the post meta table with the name `_wp_old_slug`.  So you can use `get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_wp_old_slug', $single = false );` to retrieve the former slug(s).  I see no reason this wouldn't work with CPTs, as they're just a special type of post.

#### Reference:

- [`wp_check_for_changed_slugs()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_check_for_changed_slugs)
- [`get_post_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll give that a try. Sorry it took so long for me to get back, I haven't been home.